# Qual a função do operador ~ (til) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Tentei procurar pelo Google e no SOEN, mas não encontrei nenhuma referência ao operador `~`, descobri que ele existe, pois estava lendo um livro sobre JavaScript e tinha um exemplo utilizando ele, mas o autor também não havia feito nenhuma referência ao til antes.

```javascript
var i = 10;
var j = ~i;    // j = -11
var l = ~-i;   // l = 9
var x = ~true; // x = -2
var y = ~false;// y = -1
```

Qual a função do operador `~` e quando ele é geralmente utilizado?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Esse é um operador de **negação binária**, ele opera invertendo bit a bit um número.

#### Exemplo simplificado

```
var x = 4; /* Em binário é representado como 100 */
var y = ~x; /* Agora o x invertido é representado como 011, ou seja, como o número -5,
               devido a negação complemento de 2 */
```

Utilizando os operadores binários um 9 se transforma em `000000000 000000000 00000000 00001001`, se tornando `11111111 11111111 11111111 11110110`, ou -10, quando negado pelo operador **NOT** binário (`~`).

#### Utilização

Mesmo sem muita utilidade prática é possível utilizar o operador `~` para arredondamento para baixo de números positivos negando-o duas vezes:

```
var x = ~~93.4953; //93
var y = ~~94.9999; //94
```

Isso ocorre por que os operadores binários transformam o tipo *Number*, que por padrão é o tipo *[binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)*, em 32-bit *signed*, que fazem com que os valores após a vírgula sejam ignorados.

Você pode encontrar mais exemplos na MDN:

### [Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: Na verdade em JavaScript o tipo *Number* é o tipo [*binary64* definido pelo *IEEE 754*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). O valor máximo de um inteiro em JavaScript é de [9,007,199,254,740,992](http://stackoverflow.com/a/307200), enquanto que de um número 32-bit *signed*, em termos genéricos, é de [2,147,483,647](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing).

Comment: Isso, eu estava errado. Eles só são considerados 32-bit *signed* nos operadores binários. Editado!

Comment: Apenas acrescentando: `~n` é equivalente a `-n-1`, assumindo que complemento de dois é usado. E outro método (mais comumente usado) para forçar a conversão do número em um inteiro é fazer OR com zero: `93.684|0` -> `93`.

Answer (score 17):

O operador `~` é o operador *NOT* binário ([Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria#NOT), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29)).

Exemplo:

```
> ~ 5
-6
```

`5` em binário: `0101`.

Invertendo cada bit temos: `1010`, que é `-6` em decimal.

Por quê `-6`? [Lembre-se do complemento de 2](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois)!

---

P.S.

É importante notar que, apesar do valor máximo inteiro de JavaScript ser 9,007,199,254,740,992 (2<sup>53</sup>), as operações binárias (*bitwise*) só funcionam corretamente em inteiros na faixa dos 32-bit.

[ECMAScript-262 Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5):

> Some ECMAScript operators deal only with integers in the range −2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive, or in the range 0 through 2<sup>32</sup>−1, inclusive. These operators accept any value of the Number type but first convert each such value to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer values. See the descriptions of the ToInt32 and ToUint32 operators in 9.5 and 9.6, respectively.

Esse é o caso das operações bitwise. **Então tome cuidado com valores que estouram esse limite**.

```
> ~ 2147483648
2147483647
```

O resultado correto é na verdade -2147483649 (testado no Firefox 26).

Comment: Acho que você se equivocou escolha da ilustração. Essa representa um ponto flutuante no IEEE754, que nada tem haver com codificar um inteiro em complemento de dois.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal É que em JS todos os números são IEEE 754. Os inteiros usam no máximo 52 bits, mais o sinal.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, mas ao aplicar operações bitwise, eles funcionam como se fossem inteiros representados em complemento de dois, como nesse caso. A imagem não faz sentido no contexto.

Comment: Utilizei a imagem apenas para ilustrar o complemento de 2 em javascript (que exatamente o que ela representa). Pode confundir um pouco pois em operações bitwise o js vai tratá-los como 32-bit. Removi em todo o caso.

Comment: Legal, isso mata o `Math.floor(numero);`