# Como extrair a extensão de um arquivo no Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, arquivo

Existem alguns casos onde eu preciso capturar a extensão de um arquivo (isso é, uma string com endereço do arquivo) para poder validar a extensão via Javascript.

Por exemplo do `location`:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
// /foo/bar.html
```

No caso quero pegar o `html`.

Existe o caso também de tratar a extensão de um elemento link, exemplo:

```
var path = document.querySelector('link').src;
// http://algum.site/css/estilo.css
```

No caso teria de retornar o `css`.

### Qual melhor forma de obter essa extensão?

Considerados os casos de URL:

```
'foo/bar.ext'     // 'ext'
'foo.bar/zaz.ext' // 'ext'
'foo.bar/sem_ext' // ''
'.sem_ext'        // ''
'foo/.sem_ext'    // ''
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Para obter a extensão de um arquivo de maneira pratica uso:

```
var ext = path.split('.').pop();
```

No caso o `split` dividiu o path em um array e o `pop` vai remover e retornar o último elemento desta array, exatamente a extensão que procuro.

Uma versão mais precisa seria:

```
// Pegar somente a ultima parte, afinal podem ter pastas com . no caminho
var ext = path.split('/').pop();
// se não houver extensão, retorna vazio, se houver retorna a extensão
// sendo que .htaccess é um arquivo escondido e não uma extensão
ext = ext.indexOf('.') < 1 ? '' : ext.split('.').pop();
```

Porém também é possível faze-lo utilizando `lastIndexOf` com algumas operações matemáticas para obter [melhor performance](http://jsperf.com/lastindexof-versus-split/3), exemplo:

```
function ext(path) {
    var idx = (~-path.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2;
    return path.substr((path.lastIndexOf("/") - idx > -3 ? -1 >>> 0 : idx));
}
```

Nesta segunda solução, eu utilizei o conceito apresentado pelo [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) porém de uma forma pouca coisa mais performática.

**Explicando a segunda solução**

Primeiro achamos a posição do `.`, mas como vamos usar o `substr` em seguida, é importante saber que no `substr` se você colocar um valor maior que a *string*, ele vai retornar vazio.

Então a gente usa o operador `-` pra transformar o valor em negativo.

Em seguida o operador `~` que vai inverter o valor binário (ex: `0010` vira `1101`) essa operação é feita dessa forma exatamente para pular se o arquivo começa com `.` ou se não tiver `.` nele dar um valor negativo.

Com o operador `>>>` a gente esta movendo o posicionamento em bits dentro de valor não assinado (positivo), o que no caso de ser negativo pra 0 vai dar o maior inteiro possível menos o valor que está sendo passado no resultado do calculo anterior e se for positivo nada vai acontecer ser alterado.

Então soma-se 2 pra compensar as operações `~-` no final.

Na linha seguinte temos uma condicional para que o da posição da ultima `/` seja menor que a ultima posição de ponto ou caso seja um ponto em seguida, por isso o menor que -3, de forma aplicar a mesma lógica para o `substr` caso o valor seja invalido dando um número muito grande pra ele.

- Mais sobre o [funcionamento de complemento bit-a-bit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559/qual-a-funcao-do-operador-em-javascript).
- Mais sobre o [funcionamento de deslocamento para direita não assinado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7889/qual-a-funcao-dos-operadores-e-no-javascript).

Comment: Ficou meio grande a explicação, acho que dava pra abrir perguntas e respostas dessas operações aqui no stackoverflow, pois devem interessar outros programadores.

Comment: Podemos abrir, mas achei que ficou de bom tamanho, sua resposta está bem completa agora! Se eu pudesse, votava outra vez :)

Comment: O tamanho da resposta não necessariamente é um problema. Eu prefiro uma resposta grande mas completa a uma simples e que deixa alguma informação escapar.

Answer (score 9):

A lógica para se extrair a extensão com esses requisitos é isolar a última parte do caminho, e verificar:

- Se ela está em branco, começa com ponto ou não contém ponto: retorna `''`.
- Senão: retorna o que vier após o ponto.

Você pode [quebrar o caminho em arrays](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7859), como demonstrado pelo Gabriel Gartz. **É a maneira mais simples**.

Uma opção que não envolve arrays, somente com manipulação de strings, costuma ser [mais performática](http://jsperf.com/lastindexof-versus-split/2). Trata-se de usar [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) para para quebrar o caminho:

```
function ext(path) {
    var final = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var separador = final.lastIndexOf('.');
    return separador <= 0 ? '' : final.substr(separador + 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 bem legal esse teste de performance e tudo mais que vc fez :)

Answer (score 6):

Gosto da abordagem com expressões regulares:

```
function getExtension(path) {
  var r = /\.([^./]+)$/.exec(path);
  return r && r[1] || '';
}
```

A expressão regular irá procurar por um “ponto”, seguido de quaisquer outros caracteres, exceto outro ponto ou uma barra. O `$` no final da expressão exige que seja o final da string.

Se esse padrão for encontrado na string, a função irá retornar a 1ª captura, ou seja, as letras seguindo o último ponto. Caso contrário, irá retornar string vazia.

Explicação [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5C.%28%5B%5E.%2F%5D%2B%29%24%2F)

Comment: legal vc retornar uma string vazia, pra que sua função respeite a regra de responsabilidade única. entra string sai string. pra isso use um `|| ''` no fim do return. é legal usar regexp também. +1

Comment: mas é a solução menos performática de todas: http://jsperf.com/lastindexof-versus-split/3

Comment: no meu Chrome é a mais rápida de todas: http://imgur.com/Ja65hcS

Comment: Eu acho mais claro que o método retorne `null` quando o alvo da busca dele não foi encontrado, por 2 motivos: é um padrão relativamente comum, principalmente no JS; e facilita o uso em expressões booleanas.

Comment: Bom, se o usuário tentar uma condicional com a propriedade `length` se for null vai ter que testar sempre duas vezes pra garantir que é uma string `res && res.length > 0`, em quanto se ele quer testar como Boleano, manter como string vazia funciona igual `!'' === !null`, isso é verdadeiro. Por fim temos a performance, que quando você muda o tipo de uma variável internamente um novo espaço na memória vai ser alocado para a variável que vai substituir a anterior, consumindo mais recursos. Mas javascript da a liberdade pra isso ser apenas um ponto de vista.

Answer (score 3):

Como você quer levar em conta arquivos sem extensão, como no caso do ".htaccess", requer um pouco mais de código:

```
var filename = window.location.pathname.split('/')[window.location.pathname.split('/').length-1].split('.');
var ext = filename[0].length > 0 ? filename[1] : '';
alert(ext)
```