# Qual a função dos operadores <<, >> e >>> no Javascript

Tags: javascript, operadores

Qual a função dos operadores matemáticos `<<`, `>>` e `>>>` em Javascript?

Exemplos:

- `0` ou `1` `>>` `1` é `0`
- `2` ou `3` `>>` `1` é `1`
- `4` ou `5` `>>` `1` é `2`

Mesmo vale para números negativos.

Já:

- `-1 >>> 1` é `2147483647`

E para positivos funciona igual o `>>`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Estes são os operadores de *bit shifting*. Isto é, operadores que alteram o valor da representação dos bits "empurrando-os" para um lado.

`<<` *empurra* para a esquerda e `>>` *empurra* para a direita.

O número 5, por exemplo, tem representação `000...00000101`.
`5 << 2` move os bits duas posições (preenchendo com zeros os novos lugares), pelo que passamos a ter `000...00010100`, isto é, 20.
`5 >> 2` move os bits duas posições para o outro lado, pelo que passamos a ter `000...00000001`, isto é, 1.

Na prática, o operador `x << n` multiplica `x` por 2<sup>n</sup> (por exemplo, `x << 1` multiplica por 2) e o operador `x >> n` divide por 2<sup>n</sup> (por exemplo, `x >> 1` divide por 2, truncando os resultados).

Todos estes operadores convertem para inteiros de 32 bits os valores dos operandos antes de aplicar as operações. Caso o operando da direita seja superior a 32, apenas os 5 bits significativos desse operando são usados (portanto, `x >> 2` é igual a `x >> 66`)

Para compreender como estes operadores se comportam com números negativos, é importante perceber como os números negativos são representados em memória.
O formato usado por estes operadores assume um modelo de **complemento de dois**.

Neste modelo, inverter o sinal de um número é equivalente a inverter todos os bits e depois somar 1.
Exemplo:

```
Número 2:                 00000...000010
Invertendo todos os bits: 11111...111101
Somando 1:                11111...111110
```

Logo, a representação do número `-2` é: `111111...111110`. Um número é positivo se o bit mais significativo (o mais à esquerda) for 0, e negativo se o bits mais significativo for 1.

Ao aplicar `-2 << 2` passamos a ter `11111...111000`. Que número é este?

```
Número X:                 11111...111000
Invertendo todos os bits: 00000...000111
Somando 1:                00000...001000 (que significa 8)
```

Logo `-2 << 2 === -8`. Novamente vemos que o efeito é multiplicar por 2<sup>n</sup>.

A diferença entre `>>` e `>>>` é que o `>>` preenche os bits introduzidos à esquerda com o valor do bit mais significativo do operando da esquerda, enquanto que `>>>` preenche os bits introduzidos com 0.

`-4 >> 1` dá `-2`, mas `-4 >>> 1` dá:

```
Número 4:  0000...000100
Número -4: 1111...111100
Resultado: 0111...111110 (ou seja, 2^31 - 2)
```

Podemos assim dizer que o `>>` mantém o sinal, enquanto `>>> N` dá sempre um nº positivo (desde que N > 0).

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (em inglês)

Comment: +1 bem mais completa que a minha resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

As operações de **deslocamento binário** funcionam deslocando em uma representação binária do número.

Por exemplo o valor 2 `0010` ou 3 `0011` quando deslocados para direita formam o valor 1 `0001` pois o último número acaba sendo removido e o sistema vai inserir um 0 pra compensar no inicio.

Utilizei 4 bits apenas como fins didáticos pro exemplo.

No caso de números assinados (que permitem positivos e negativos, o deslocamento pode ser feito para ambos os lados), já para números não assinados `>>>` a operação só pode ser feita pra direita.

Pois como não contém o digito que identifica se o valor é positivo ou negativo, este valor sempre vai ser positivo e uma vez que ele é menor que zero, passa ser o maior número positivo possível.

Exemplo:
`-1 >>> 0` é `4294967295`

Pois 0 é `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` e -1 no caso ele iria mudar a assinatura, o que causa uma inversão completa, empurrando todos os zeros e substituindo-os por `1` que resulta em `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

Para testar os valores binários obtidos uma solução simples é o uso da classe `Number` e o método `toString(2)`, exemplo:

```
Number(-2 >>> 0).toString(2) // "11111111111111111111111111111110"
```