# Qual a função de << (dois less than) em Java?

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private static String encode(long number){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    number = number  < 0 ? ~(number << 1) : number << 1;
    while (number >= 0x20) {
        builder.append(Character.toChars((int) ((0x20 | (number & 0x1f)) + 63)));
        number >>= 5;
    }
    builder.append(Character.toChars((int) (number + 63)));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Gostaria de ajuda pra tentar entender as seguintes partes:

> number = number  < 0 ? ~(number << 1) : number << 1;
>
> ((0x20 | (number & 0x1f)) + 63)

Comment: Se não me engano já tem a resposta pra isso aqui no site. O problema é que a busca não reconhece caracteres como **`<`** (até por isso que fiz a edição)

Comment: Achei essa pergunta após a edição do @jbueno http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050989/double-greater-than-sign-in-java

Comment: Relacionada: [Como funciona o deslocamento de bits em C/C++?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10174/18246)

Comment: @bigown mal pergunte a utilidade em javascript é exatamene igual a em java?

Comment: @diegofm exatamente. Nenhuma linguagem que eu conheço faz diferente. Seria praticamente dizer que as operações aritméticas são diferentes dependendo da linguagem.

Comment: @jbueno acho que caberia como duplicata também, é uma pena que o mecanismo não permita escolher mais que uma a não ser quando duas pessoas o fazem, o que obviamente não acontece quando um moderador fecha.

Comment: @bigown  Tenho mais 1 dúvida ainda, Se puder me ajudar !  O  ` **~** `  faz o que? Muito Obrigado!]

Comment: Eu ia votar como duplicata, na verdade, mas quando voltei já estava marcada @bigown

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Abra outra pergunta. Esta já foi fechada.

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1559/101