# Escolhas aleatórias em um array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Opa galera, sou novo tanto no stackoverflow quanto no mundo do JS!

Seguinte, eu estou tendo dificuldades em fazer um script que escolha uma string dentro de um array
escrevi o código da seguinte forma:

```
let choices = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Math.floor(choices)
```

e retorna not a number o que é perfeitamente entendível, já que os valores do array são strings, mas como
havia dito sou novo no mundo do JS e não sei se o método Math é o melhor para a tarefa, o mesmo script
em python seria muito mais simples:

```
import random

choices = ['a', 'b', 'c']
random.choice(choises)
```

Gostaria de saber se os senhores(a) teriam alguma sugestão de método no JS que retornasse o valor como no
código em pythom. Desde já grato!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar uma função

```js
let choices = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function rand(choices) {
    console.log(choices[~~(choices.length * Math.random())]);
}
rand(choices);
```

[Qual a função do operador ~ (til) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-operador-til-em-javascript/1561#1561)

Answer (score 9):

Poderia implementar da seguinte maneira:

```
choices[Math.floor((Math.random() * choices.length))]
```

Comment: Ótimo mano, muito simples sintaxe até que parecida com python! Solucionou meu problema valeu!

Answer (score 6):

Bom, a abordagem pro teu problema é bem simples. Em JS, recomendo você gerar um número aleatório de 0 até o tamanho da sua array com o array.length, e depois acessar um indice aleatório com esse mesmo número gerado. Ficaria assim:

```
let choices = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let tamanho_array = choices.length
let n_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho_array);
let retorno_aleatorio = choices[n_aleatorio]
```

Assim, a  variável retorno_aleatório vai ter teu valor random.

Comment: Valeu mano! Ajudou muito

Answer (score -1):

Eu utilizei essas três linhas de código para escolher de forma aleatória uma string do array e atribuir ela para a variável palavra:

```
let bancoPalavras = ["cigar", "rebut", "sissy"];
let n_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * bancoPalavras.length);
word = bancoPalavras[n_aleatorio];
```