# Como mudar o background-color toda vez que a página atualizar? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, background-color

**Como posso fazer uma função com Javascript que:** sempre que atualizar a página, altere o `background-color` da tag `body` para uma das cores predefinidas? **Exemplo:** *Quero definir umas 3 cores diferentes, para que sempre que a página for atualizada, altere para uma dessas 3 cores aleatóriamente, e isso ocorra sempre que a página for atualizada.* Não sei como fazer essa função, até agora o que eu tenho é isso:

```
function mudarCores() {
    document.body.style.background = "#FF00FF";
}
```

Comment: Como eu faria: Colocaria uma id no body. Salvaria as cores possíveis dentro de uma array. Usaria a função Math.random para selecionar uma dessas cores. Em seguida usaria getElementById('idDoBody).style.background = CorEscolhida.
Me conta se deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso, é gravar a informação da cor no `localStorage` do navegador e no `onLoad` da página, ler essa informação e trocar a cor com base nela.

Exemplo:

```
//Evento de onload, será quando a página for acessada ou sofrer uma atualização
window.onload = function(){
  //Pego a cor no localStorage
  let color = localStorage.getItem("color");

  //Índice de busca da cor
  let indexColor = 0;

  //Paleta de cores pré-definidas
  let colors = ["#FF00FF", "#464131", "#269486"];

  //Se a cor não estiver nula, já existe algum no localStorage, então usamos ela
  //caso contrário, começa em zero, conforme o indexColor declaro anteriormente
  if (color != null) {
    indexColor = parseInt(color);
  }

  //Seto a cor de fundo
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[indexColor];

  //Incremento a cor para mudar no próximo carregamento
  indexColor++;

  //Se a cor estiver do tamanho do array, preciso recomeçar a contagem
  //caso contrário, posso acessar uma posição inválida do array
  if (indexColor === colors.length) {
    indexColor = 0;    
  }

  //Gravo no localStorage o índice da próxima cor que será usada
  localStorage.setItem("color", indexColor.toString());
}
```

---

Documentações:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que o documento carregar selecione uma cor [aleatóriamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463677/137387).

```js
const cores = ['black', 'red', 'navy'];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = cores[Math.floor(Math.random() * cores.length)]
});
```

Evento [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).
Objeto [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window).