# O que significa "!!~" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, operadores

Estou estudando JavaScript e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
manageLag(selected) {
    if(!!~this.selections.indexOf(selected.url)) {
        selected.at += 5
        return;
    }

    this.selections.push(selected.url)
}
```

Eu não consegui entender o que o `if` está verificando. O que o `!!~` está fazendo?

Comment: +1 eu também não sei kkkkkkk. Eu chuto que `!!` seja para converter para Booleano e `~` tenha a ver com binários ou bitwise, mas não manjo muito.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual o sentido de usar dupla negação em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

São três operadores trabalhando em conjunto, sendo dois deles o operador lógico de negação (*logic NOT* — `!`) e o terceiro, o [operador *bitwise* de negação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1559/69296) (*bitwise NOT* — `~`).

Nesse caso, o primeiro operador a ser *avaliado* será o *bitwise NOT*. Utilizá-lo em conjunto com o `indexOf` era uma prática relativamente comum em JavaScript. Vamos entender o porquê.

De modo geral, o *bitwise NOT* (`~`), quando aplicado em números, funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
~N -> -(N + 1)
```

Assim, ao o aplicarmos em `-1`, temos:

```
~(-1) -> -(-1 + 1) -> -(0) -> 0
```

Alguns exemplos:

```js
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3].forEach((num) => {
  console.log('~' + num, '=', ~num);
});
```

Geralmente, queremos obter uma resposta booleana (verdadeiro ou falso) para saber se algum elemento está contido em uma lista (ou string) ou não. No entanto, historicamente, o JavaScript só contava com o método `indexOf` para fazer essa busca que, por alguma razão (provavelmente para servir como [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21768/69296)), retorna `-1` se o elemento não existe na lista.

Assim, uma forma concisa de transformar o retorno em um valor *truthy* ou *falsy* é utilizar o operador `~`. Para `-1`, teremos `0` (que é *falsy*) e, para qualquer outro número, teremos valores *truthy*.

Em seguida, utilizamos os dois operadores `!!` para converter o resultado do `~` em, de fato, um booleano. [Esta resposta dá mais detalhes sobre isso.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29014/69296) Também poderia utilizar o construtor [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), que é uma forma mais explícita (porém menos concisa) para se fazer o mesmo. Vejamos:

```js
// Note que, para `0`, teremos `false`. Para qualquer
// valor numárico diferente de zero, teremos `true`.

[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2].forEach((num) => {
  console.log('!!' + num, '=', !!num);
  console.log(`Boolean(${num}) =`, Boolean(num));
});
```

Em suma, combinando a dupla negação (`!!`) com o *bitwise NOT*, garantimos que, para o resultado `-1` de `indexOf`, teremos `false`. Para qualquer outro resultado de `indexOf`, a expressão de operadores avaliará para `true`.

---

Atualmente, já existem métodos que retornam um valor booleano para verificar se uma lista contém algum elemento. Alguns exemplos são:

- [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) (introduzido no ECMAScript 2016 - ES7)
- [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 - ES6)

Portanto, se você está em algum ambiente que suporte esses novos métodos, o uso do `!!~` pode ser visto como desnecessário. É, decerto, também, menos compreensível para aqueles que estão começando a aprender JavaScript.

Comment: tinha começado a editar uma resposta mas, nem preciso mais :D

Comment: Sempre pontual @RicardoPontual.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi mesmo rápido :D

Answer (score 9):

O código em questão pode ser dividido em partes para facilitar o entendimento:

- `!` representa a negação de algo;
- `!!` é a negação da negação, geralmente usado para converter valores [*truthy* e *falsy*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/100416)  em `boolean`
- `~` é um operador de inversão binária (veja [Qual a função do operador ~ (til) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1559/100416)).

```js
const stringVazia = "";
const num100 = 100;

console.log("!stringVazia:", !stringVazia);
console.log("!!stringVazia:", !!stringVazia);
console.log("stringVazia === !!stringVazia:", stringVazia === !!stringVazia);
console.log("~stringVazia:", ~stringVazia);
console.log("!~stringVazia:", !~stringVazia);
console.log("!!~stringVazia:", !!~stringVazia);

console.log('');

console.log("!num100:", !num100);
console.log("!!num100:", !!num100);
console.log("num100 === !!num100:", num100 === !!num100);
console.log("~num100:", ~num100);
console.log("!~num100:", !~num100);
console.log("!!~num100:", !!~num100);
```

Comment: Muito bom, mas confesso que nunca nem vi sobre isso XD. Nunca cheguei a ver um codigo usando isso. Ao meu ver, esse operador `~` funciona somente com numeros, seria isso?

Comment: @CmteCardeal depende do que você quer dizer com "funciona". Sim, ele é feito para números. Você pode ver na especificação do [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bitwise-not-operator): o valor dado e o valor retornado são convertidos para inteiros 32-bit, então uma `string` acaba sendo `NaN`.